# How to center all column items in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have this QML code, but I need to center horizontally Text and Rectangle, how can I do it? Can it be done somehow except settimg horizontal alignment for both of them< can I write some dtyle that will be applied to all children of column element?

Can I also set some styles to Column that will make automatical vertical spaces between my elements?

I want to make effect same to following css

```css
.col{
    dissplay:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And here id my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
//    visible:true
    ColumnLayout{

        Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignHCenter

        Text{
            text:"CONTROL\n MANAGEMENT\n SYSTEM"
            color:"#999999"
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            width:parent.width
        }

        Rectangle{
            width:100
            height:100
            color:"#ff0000"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i found this working solution

Answer (score 0):

i found this working solution

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    visible:true
    Item{
//        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
        x:(parent.width-this.childrenRect.width)/2
        ColumnLayout{

            Text{
                Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignHCenter
                text:"CONTROL\n MANAGEMENT\n SYSTEM"
                color:"#999999"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                width:parent.width
            }

            Rectangle{
                Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignHCenter
                width:300
                height:100
                color:"#ff0000"
            }

            Rectangle{
                Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignHCenter
                width:200
                height:100
                color:"#ff0000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I still have a question if I can use some another methods, I do not want to write `Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignHCenter` in every child element.

Comment: Regarding your question: you will still have to write this in all elements, unless you make a new QML object class that has this Layout.Alignment built in, which all of your child elements inherit from.